# Animating Damped Oscillator

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, animation

I was able to simulate a mass-spring system under damped oscillations. However, I wanted to add a subplot of position vs time and another subplot velocity vs position (phase path) so that I will be having three animations. How can I add them? The source code that I used is shown below

Update: I tried adding the first subplot position vs time but I cannot get the desired curve for it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation


#Constants
w = np.pi #angular frequency
b = np.pi * 0.2  #damping parameter

#Function that implements rk4 integration
def rk4(t, x, f, dt):
    dx1 = f(t, x)*dt
    dx2 = f(t+0.5*dt, x+0.5*dx1)*dt
    dx3 = f(t+0.5*dt, x+0.5*dx2)*dt
    dx4 = f(t+dt, x+dx3)*dt
    return x+dx1/6.0+dx2/3.0+dx3/3.0+dx4/6.0

#Function that returns dX/dt for the linearly damped oscillator
def dXdt(t, X):
    x = X[0]
    vx = X[1]
    ax = -2*b*vx - w**2*x
    return np.array([vx, ax])

#Initialize Variables
x0 = 5.0 #Initial x position
vx0 = 1.0 #Initial x Velocity

#Setting time array for graph visualization
dt = 0.05
N = 200
x = np.zeros(N)
vx = np.zeros(N)
y = []
# integrate equations of motion using rk4;
# X is a vector that contains the positions and velocities being integrated
X = np.array([x0, vx0])


for i in range(N):
    x[i] = X[0]
    vx[i] = X[1]
    y.append(0)
    # update the vector X to the next time step
    X = rk4(i*dt, X, dXdt, dt)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(8,6))
fig.suptitle(r' Damped Oscillation with $\beta$$\approx$' + str(round(b,2)) + r' and $\omega$$\approx$'
             + str(round(w,2)), fontsize=16)
line1, = ax1.plot([], [], lw=10,c="blue",ls="-",ms=50,marker="s",mfc="gray",fillstyle="none",mec="black",markevery=2)
line2, = ax2.plot([], [], lw=2, color='r')
time_template = '\nTime = %.1fs'
time_text = ax1.text(0.1, 0.9, '', transform=ax1.transAxes)

for ax in [ax1, ax2]:
    ax1.set_xlim(1.2*min(x), 1.2*max(x))
    ax2.set_ylim(1.2*min(x), 1.2*max(x),1)
    ax2.set_xlim(0, N*dt)
    ax1.set_yticklabels([])

def init():
    line1.set_data([], [])
    line2.set_data([], [])
    time_text.set_text('')
    return line1, line2, time_text

def animate(i):
    thisx1 = [x[i],0]
    thisy1 = [y[i],0]
    thisx2 = [i*dt,0]
    thisy2 = [x[i],0]
    line1.set_data(thisx1, thisy1)
    line2.set_data(thisx2, thisy2)
    time_text.set_text(time_template % (i*dt))
    return line1, line2, time_text  

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, N),
                              interval=50, blit=True, init_func=init,repeat=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some minors changes to your initial code, the most noteworthy being:

```
thisx1 = [x[i],0]
thisy1 = [y[i],0]
thisx2 = [i*dt,0]
thisy2 = [x[i],0]
line1.set_data(thisx1, thisy1)
line2.set_data(thisx2, thisy2)

# should be written like this
line1.set_data([x[i],0], [y[i],0])
line2.set_data(t[:i], x[:i])
line3.set_data(x[:i], vx[:i])
```

The working version, with phase space plot in green, is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation


#Constants
w = np.pi #angular frequency
b = np.pi * 0.2  #damping parameter

#Function that implements rk4 integration
def rk4(t, x, f, dt):
    dx1 = f(t, x)*dt
    dx2 = f(t+0.5*dt, x+0.5*dx1)*dt
    dx3 = f(t+0.5*dt, x+0.5*dx2)*dt
    dx4 = f(t+dt, x+dx3)*dt
    return x+dx1/6.0+dx2/3.0+dx3/3.0+dx4/6.0

#Function that returns dX/dt for the linearly damped oscillator
def dXdt(t, X):
    x = X[0]
    vx = X[1]
    ax = -2*b*vx - w**2*x
    return np.array([vx, ax])

#Initialize Variables
x0 = 5.0 #Initial x position
vx0 = 1.0 #Initial x Velocity

#Setting time array for graph visualization
dt = 0.05
N = 200
t = np.linspace(0,N*dt,N,endpoint=False)
x = np.zeros(N)
vx = np.zeros(N)
y = np.zeros(N)
# integrate equations of motion using rk4;
# X is a vector that contains the positions and velocities being integrated
X = np.array([x0, vx0])

for i in range(N):
    x[i] = X[0]
    vx[i] = X[1]
    # update the vector X to the next time step
    X = rk4(i*dt, X, dXdt, dt)

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3,1, figsize=(8,12))
fig.suptitle(r' Damped Oscillation with $\beta$$\approx$' + str(round(b,2)) + r' and $\omega$$\approx$'
             + str(round(w,2)), fontsize=16)
line1, = ax1.plot([], [], lw=10,c="blue",ls="-",ms=50,marker="s",mfc="gray",fillstyle="none",mec="black",markevery=2)
line2, = ax2.plot([], [], lw=1, color='r')
line3, = ax3.plot([], [], lw=1, color='g')
time_template = '\nTime = %.1fs'
time_text = ax1.text(0.1, 0.9, '', transform=ax1.transAxes)


ax1.set_xlim(1.2*min(x), 1.2*max(x))
ax1.set_xlabel('x')
ax1.set_ylabel('y')

ax2.set_ylim(1.2*min(x), 1.2*max(x),1)
ax2.set_xlim(0, N*dt)
ax2.set_xlabel('t')
ax2.set_ylabel('x')

ax3.set_xlim(1.2*min(x), 1.2*max(x),1)
ax3.set_ylim(1.2*min(vx), 1.2*max(vx),1)
ax3.set_xlabel('x')
ax3.set_ylabel('vx')

def init():
    line1.set_data([], [])
    line2.set_data([], [])
    line3.set_data([], [])
    time_text.set_text('')
    return line1, line2, line3, time_text

def animate(i):
    line1.set_data([x[i],0], [y[i],0])
    line2.set_data(t[:i], x[:i])
    line3.set_data(x[:i], vx[:i])
    time_text.set_text(time_template % (i*dt))
    return line1, line2, line3, time_text  

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, N),
                              interval=50, blit=True, init_func=init,repeat=False)

ani.save('anim.gif')
```

and gives:

[image: anim.gif]

Comment: Thank you! I was about to edit the thread for the update then I saw this. For this case, how can I label the axis for each subplot?

Comment: The same way you set your ax lim, but with the methods `set_xlabel` and `set_ylabel`, check examples in matplotlib documentation.

Comment: I tried doing so but it only labels on the third subplot. When using `ax1.set_xlabel` , it gives error.

Comment: Try harder. I updated my answer.  Again, look at some examples : https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/index.html

Comment: Thanks! I will try to check the link.

Comment: It worked! I now know where I went wrong. Cheers for the help, pal.

Comment: Hi again! I would like to improve this program by adding appropriate markers. As such, I posted a thread at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67564017/damped-oscillator-spring). I want that at the last time instant, the animation should stop at the equilibrium position. Is there any way to extend the blue line to the left?