# Damped Oscillator Spring

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

good day! I am looking forward to enhance the animation of the damped oscillation program but I do not know how to extend the blue line towards the left portion of the first subplot so that the box will be back to its equilibrium position same as the photo shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation


#Ask user to input parameters
w = np.pi
b = np.pi*0.2

#Function that implements rk4 integration
def rk4(t, x, f, dt):
    dx1 = f(t, x)*dt
    dx2 = f(t+0.5*dt, x+0.5*dx1)*dt
    dx3 = f(t+0.5*dt, x+0.5*dx2)*dt
    dx4 = f(t+dt, x+dx3)*dt
    return x+dx1/6.0+dx2/3.0+dx3/3.0+dx4/6.0

#Function that returns dX/dt for the linearly damped oscillator
def dXdt(t, X):
    x = X[0]
    vx = X[1]
    ax = -2*b*vx - w**2*x
    return np.array([vx, ax])

#Initialize Variables
x0 = 5.0 #Initial x position
vx0 = 1.0 #Initial x Velocity

#Setting time array for graph visualization (for the first 10 seconds)
dt = 0.01
N = 1000
x = np.zeros(N)
vx = np.zeros(N)
y = []

# integrate equations of motion using rk4;
# X is a vector that contains the positions and velocities being integrated
X = np.array([x0, vx0])
t = np.arange(0, dt*N, dt)
for i in range(N):
    x[i] = X[0]
    vx[i] = X[1]
    y.append(0)
    # update the vector X to the next time step
    X = rk4(i*dt, X, dXdt, dt)

#Ploting the results in with 3 rows and 1 colum (1 plot each row)
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3,1, figsize=(10,10))
fig.suptitle(r' Damped Oscillation with $\beta$$\approx$' + str(round(b,2)) + r' and $\omega$$\approx$'
             + str(round(w,2)), fontsize=16)

#Simulation
line1, = ax1.plot([], [], lw=10,c="blue",ls="-",ms=50,marker="s",mfc="gray",fillstyle="none",mec="black",markevery=2)
time_template = '\nTime = %.1fs'
time_text = ax1.text(0.1, 0.9, '', transform=ax1.transAxes)
line5,=ax1.plot([],[],lw=2,c="black",marker="^")

#Position and Velocity Time graph on twin axis
line2, = ax2.plot([], [], lw=2, color='g', label='x')
line4, = ax2.plot([], [], lw=2, color='m', label= r'$\dot{x}$')

#Phase Path
line3, = ax3.plot([], [], lw=2, color='r')


#Marker


#Setting limits for the axes by scaling a bit for nice visualiztion
for ax in [ax1, ax2, ax3]:
    #For the visualization
    ax1.set_xlim(1.2*min(x), 1.2*max(x))
    #For the position and velocity time graph
    ax2.set_ylim(1.4*min(vx), 1.4*max(x)) #
    ax2.set_xlim(0, N*dt) #
    #For the phase path
    ax3.set_ylim(1.2*min(vx), 1.2*max(vx))
    ax3.set_xlim(1.2*min(x), 1.2*max(x))

#Animating the results
def init():
    line1.set_data([], [])
    line2.set_data([], [])
    line3.set_data([], [])
    line4.set_data([], [])
    time_text.set_text('')
    return line1, line2, line3, line4, time_text

#Function adding each ith coordinate element in the graph to appropriate data points
def animate(i):
    line1.set_data([x[i],0], [y[i],0]) 
    line2.set_data(t[:i], x[:i])
    line3.set_data(x[:i], vx[:i])
    line4.set_data(t[:i], vx[:i])
    line5.set_data([0.0,0.0],[-0.4,-0.03])
    time_text.set_text(time_template % (i*dt))
    return line1, line2, line3, line4, time_text  

#Call the FuncAnimation to animate
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, len(t),
                              interval=10, blit=True, init_func=init,repeat=False)

#Plotting and identifying axis labels
fig.tight_layout(pad=5.0)
ax1.set_xlabel('x (m)', fontsize=12)
ax2.set_xlabel('t (s)', fontsize=12)
ax2.set_ylabel(r'x , $\dot{x}$', fontsize=12)
ax3.set_xlabel('x (m)', fontsize=12)
ax3.set_ylabel(r'$\dot{x}$ (m/s)', fontsize=12)
ax1.set_title("Visualization", fontsize=12)
ax2.set_title("Position and Velocity Time Graph", fontsize=12)
ax2.legend()
ax3.set_title("Phase Path", fontsize=12)
```

Desired output: [image: Photo]

I also included a link where the output should be similar to [Link](https://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/ega/teaching/s2-y16-l21.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your previous code should just be updated by offsetting the `x` position of the left of the spring. In order to do this, you coul specify the length of the spring at rest, for instance `L = 5.`, which gives:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation


#Constants
w = np.pi #angular frequency
b = np.pi * 0.2  #damping parameter

# length of the spring at rest (>0)
L = 5.

#Function that implements rk4 integration
def rk4(t, x, f, dt):
    dx1 = f(t, x)*dt
    dx2 = f(t+0.5*dt, x+0.5*dx1)*dt
    dx3 = f(t+0.5*dt, x+0.5*dx2)*dt
    dx4 = f(t+dt, x+dx3)*dt
    return x+dx1/6.0+dx2/3.0+dx3/3.0+dx4/6.0

#Function that returns dX/dt for the linearly damped oscillator
def dXdt(t, X):
    x = X[0]
    vx = X[1]
    ax = -2*b*vx - w**2*x
    return np.array([vx, ax])

#Initialize Variables
x0 = 5.0 #Initial x position
vx0 = 1.0 #Initial x Velocity

#Setting time array for graph visualization
dt = 0.05
N = 200
t = np.linspace(0,N*dt,N,endpoint=False)
x = np.zeros(N)
vx = np.zeros(N)
y = np.zeros(N)
# integrate equations of motion using rk4;
# X is a vector that contains the positions and velocities being integrated
X = np.array([x0, vx0])

for i in range(N):
    x[i] = X[0]
    vx[i] = X[1]
    # update the vector X to the next time step
    X = rk4(i*dt, X, dXdt, dt)

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3,1, figsize=(8,12))
fig.suptitle(r' Damped Oscillation with $\beta$$\approx$' + str(round(b,2)) + r' and $\omega$$\approx$'
             + str(round(w,2)), fontsize=16)
line1, = ax1.plot([], [], lw=10,c="blue",ls="-",ms=50,marker="s",mfc="gray",fillstyle="none",mec="black",markevery=2)
line2, = ax2.plot([], [], lw=1, color='r')
line3, = ax3.plot([], [], lw=1, color='g')
time_template = '\nTime = %.1fs'
time_text = ax1.text(0.2, 0.9, '', transform=ax1.transAxes)


ax1.set_xlim(-delta_x-1, 1.2*max(x))
ax1.plot([-L,-L],[-0.04,0.04],color='black',lw=10)
ax1.plot([-L,-L],[-0.04,0.04],'k--')
ax1.plot([x0,x0],[-0.04,0.04],'k--') # initial condition
ax1.plot([0,0],[-0.04,0.04],'k--') # rest
ax1.set_xlabel('x')
ax1.set_ylabel('y')

ax2.set_ylim(1.2*min(x), 1.2*max(x),1)
ax2.set_xlim(0, N*dt)
ax2.set_xlabel('t')
ax2.set_ylabel('x')

ax3.set_xlim(1.2*min(x), 1.2*max(x),1)
ax3.set_ylim(1.2*min(vx), 1.2*max(vx),1)
ax3.set_xlabel('x')
ax3.set_ylabel('vx')

def init():
    line1.set_data([], [])
    line2.set_data([], [])
    line3.set_data([], [])
    time_text.set_text('')
    return line1, line2, line3, time_text

def animate(i):
    line1.set_data([x[i],-L], [y[i],0])
    line2.set_data(t[:i], x[:i])
    line3.set_data(x[:i], vx[:i])
    time_text.set_text(time_template % (i*dt))
    return line1, line2, line3, time_text  

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, N),
                              interval=50, blit=True, init_func=init,repeat=False)

ani.save('anim.gif')
```

which now gives:

[image: anim.gif]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think there is something wrong with the output. The initial position of the particle is at `x=5` and should go back to its relaxed position defined as `x=0` at the end of the simulation. Thus, as a consequence, the next two subplots entail a result that does not match the theoretical one.

Comment: This is just a matter of reference frame... I have updated my answer accordingly. You should definitely try to understand how matplotlib works; your question does not really differ from the previous one you asked...